# Python: urllib2 handle multiple openers

Tags: python, request, urllib2, webrequest, urllib

I have to keep 2 urllib2 openers, one for direct requests and the second to make requests via proxy server and I've to rebuild opener switch between requests.

How to keep context openers for example **direct** and **proxy** separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect your confusion stems from using `install_opener` and `urllib2.urlopen`. Instead, just call `build_opener` twice and store the results in separate objects. Then you can use the appropriate opener when needed.

Example:

```
import urllib2
direct = urllib2.build_opener()
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://www.example.com:3128/'})
proxied = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)


direct.open('http://stackoverflow.com') # opens directly
proxied.open('http://stackoverflow.com') # opens through proxy
```